# Increasing font size dynamically on every click through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to figure out a way through I could dynamically increase fontsize of desired element, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example">
A div with class="example"
</div>

<div class="example">
Another div with class="example"
</div>

<p>This is a p element with class="example".</p>

<p>This is a <span class="example">span</span> element with                Class="example" inside another p element.</p>

<p>Click the button to change the background color of all elements with class="example".</p>

<button class="example" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, the problem is that, when I click the button the font size of the hilighted elements gets increased, but when I click the button again, the stile remains the same e.g. before click fontsize = 12px, after click it becomes 24px, at this point I want that the size increase further when I click the button again, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently your function is only doing `x[i].style.fontSize = "xx-large";`, which means "set the font size to xx-large", and not "increase the font size".

You should get the value of `x[i].style.fontSize`, and write a new increased value (probably in pixels).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase font-size by *2 everytime do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.fontSize = ( parseInt( x[i].style.fontSize ) * 2 ) + 'px';
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but, sadly, it didn't worked.